# Android face recognition by dlib issue

Tags: android, java-native-interface, face-recognition, dlib

I am using the following link to achieve the face recognition in my app

[This link is for android face recognition](https://github.com/gv22ga/dlib-face-recognition-android)

Issue: I am not able to run/compile/build this directory in android studio as this doesn't contain build.gradle files.

I have also tried to import its app level module (which contains gradle file) but it is also dependent on some file(**dlib folder and CMakeLists.txt file**) which are in project hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

The android project directory, which you are supposed to import into Android Studio is the `dlib-face-recognition-app` directory. The `dlib-face-recognition-app` directory contains a project level build.gradle file, and the `dlib-face-recognition-app/demo` directory contains the "app-level" build.gradle

Comment: this is already mention in question that i have imported the project as you are telling...but the problem is the 2 files/folders are missing (dlib folder and CMakeLists.txt) which are present in project level hierarchy(outside the android project).

Comment: the question didn't mention any CMakeLists.txt. It only mentioned missing build.gradle files, which I pointed out are in the dlib-face-recognition-app

Comment: I just cloned the project and imported the dlib-face-recognition-app directory in my android studio, and voila it builds and runs the demo app. I don't even have NDK installed. I think the dlib folder you need is inside this same directory as the demo folder. My Android Studio shows 3 modules (demo, dlib and library) and it works fine.

Comment: owsega the dlib folder you are talking about is not same as the dlib folder present the parent directory because in this dlib folder which is in parent directory has CMakeLists.txt file which is important.and  i need this and also Jni folder, which is also in parent directory. (Parent directory = outside the dlib-face-recognition-app )